# Lazarus (Delphi) SQLite при чтение в поток Blob данных приходит не вся запись из базы

Tags: pascal, delphi, sqlite

Здравствуйте Уважаемые знатоки.
Вот кусок кода  -

```
procedure BlobReadFromFile();
var
  blob: TStream;
begin
  blob := Form1.Sqlite3Dataset2.CreateBlobStream(Form1.Sqlite3Dataset2.FieldByName('Photo'), bmRead);
  Form1.Caption := Form1.Sqlite3Dataset2.FieldByName('NAME_E').AsString;
  try
    blob.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

    with TFileStream.Create('img/tmp.jpeg', fmCreate) do
      try
        CopyFrom(blob, blob.Size)
      finally
        Free
      end;
  finally
    blob.Free
  end;
end;
```

В результате в файл записывается только 4 символа из поля с блоб данными.

Comment: НУ и Да вопрос очевиден, почему не все значение а только 4 символа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так попробовать, только это с использованием стандартного Query:

```
aMStr:TMemoryStream;
aField:TBlobField;
begin
   aMStr:TMemoryStream.Create;
   try
      aField:=(MyQuery.FieldByName('IMG_FIELD_NAME')) as TBlobField);
      aField.SaveToStream(aMStr);
      aMStr.Position:=0;
      MyImage1.Picture.LoadFromStream(aMStr); //если копируем на имэйдж на форме
   finally
      aMStr.free;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: спасибо так и сделал (: сам как то дошел, ну примерно так тока с учетом особенностей lazarus а, странно что компонент весь blob Не подтянул ну и черт с ним (: